# Visual Studio 2008 can't recognize control(in webform page) in partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I insert a Textbox control in webform page,but I can't find it in partial class when I use it like **this.txtPaySerialNumber.Text**,It looks like I had not insert that in webform page.
The old control I had inserted had no problem. I have develop web form a year, this crazy thing happened only in vs2008.(My OS is Windows 8 64).

Comment: Need more information, "webform like this:" is missing the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear without an example of your scenario, but a couple of things to check....

Make sure you're control is defined in the page (and properly, check the error view for bad markup declarations, etc.):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PaySerialNumber />
```

<sub>You'll likely noticed I summarily abandoned [the awful *Hungarian Notation*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).</sub>

Then in the code-behind, access it (omitting the double `this` prefix (which I'm not sure whether to take literally from your post or not):

```
PaySerialNumber.Text = "some text";
```

If that fails, try it in the markup file itself:

```
<script runat="server" language="CSharp">
  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    PaySerialNumber.Text = "some text";
  }
</script>
```

If that works, then you likely have a mismatched page declaration, so it's not pointing to the right code-behind file.

If all else fails and the page, code-behind, or whatever, still isn't seeing the thing, then try a "clean solution and then "rebuild"; perhaps even restarting VS to reload the project after a clean.

If it *still* isn't working, then we need more information.

Comment: I had find the problem . VS2008 did not generate

Comment: I had find the problem . VS2008 did not generate corresponding code for the control.It seems there have some compatible problem in vs2008 with windows 8 64.Thank you all the same .